# How to Get Data in servlet?

Tags: java, web-services, http, servlets

I created a webservice using servlet and tomcat 6.0. I created sample java application to call the web service and its working fine. i need to send some data while calling web service. I created in java application as follows

```
StringEntity zStringEntityL = new StringEntity(zAPIInputStringP.toString());
zStringEntityL.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
        "application/json"));
HttpParams aHttpParamsL = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(aHttpParamsL, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(aHttpParamsL, HTTP.UTF_8);

SchemeRegistry aSchemeRegistryL = new SchemeRegistry();
aSchemeRegistryL.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));

ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(aHttpParamsL, aSchemeRegistryL);
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, aHttpParamsL);
HttpPost aHttpPostL = new HttpPost(URL + zAPIName);
aHttpPostL.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic");



aHttpPostL.setEntity(zStringEntityL);
HttpResponse aHttpResponseL;
aHttpResponseL = client.execute(aHttpPostL);
```

Here "zAPIInputStringP" is my data in JSON format.
In webservice how i need to get those data? I checked in debug mode in eclispe, i cant able to find it.

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    //How to get data?
}
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send the data to a servlet via post method, the data is available via **input stream**. Following is how  your post method should look like.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

String zAPIInputStringP = "";

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                request.getInputStream()));
String line = in.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    zAPIInputStringP += line;
    line = in.readLine();
}


}
```

You JSON string is contained in `zAPIInputStringP`.

Answer (score 0):

This is much simpler. and basically looks like this:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
      response.setContentType("application/json");
    // Get the printwriter object from response to write the required json object to the output stream      
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    // Assuming your json object is **zStringEntityL**, perform the following, it will return your json object  
    StringEntity zStringEntityL = new StringEntity(zAPIInputStringP.toString());
    out.print(zStringEntityL);
    out.flush();
    }
```